# How to get current fillColor of google maps polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a way to get the *current* fillColor of polygons with google maps api.

```
map.data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.getProperty('name'));
});
```

Which gives me the name associated with each polygon according to the geoJSON data.

It's pretty clear how to set style properties for these polygons but I don't see any way in the documentation to get the current fillColor.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve style of individual features of `google.maps.data` layer. You can retrieve the global style of data layer, which you previously assigned using `map.data.setStyle({StylingObject})` like this:

```
map.data.getStyle();
```

If you assigned styles using styling function (`map.data.setStyle(function(entry){..StylingFunction..})`) you cannot get the styles, but you should be able to determine them based on the `StylingFunction` you provided and properties of the current feature.

Also you cannot get styles assigned using `map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {..})`. But you can set properties with the same name to the feature when you assign  style to it, and then retrieve the properties, not the styling. So you would have:

```
map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {
   fillColor:red,
   opacity:0.5
});
feature.setProperty('fillColor', 'red');
feature.setProperty('opacity', '0.5');
```

and when you want to retrieve the styles then you can go with:

```
map.data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.getProperty('fillColor')); //.. or opacity, or anything you set with setProperty
});
```